# Turbolinks are not working with bootstrap select2 in Rails 4.2.4 Ruby 2.2.4

Tags: jquery-select2, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

When I first time load my page, select2 will work properly... But if I go to other links, we wouldn't be able to see select2 unless we reload the page.

Here's my code:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0'
gem "select2-rails"
```

application.js:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
```

application.css:

```
*= require select2
```

index.html.erb:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using turbolinks, you need to change the structure on ready to

```
<script>
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() { 
    $("#e1").select2(); 
  });
</script>
```

In your application.js, prefer to require select2 before turbolinks.

```
//= require select2
//= require turbolinks
```